# Confusion regarding working of protected[some_scope] and inheritance in scala

Tags: scala, import, intellij-idea, package, protected

This question is about protected scope of scala. Following code runs perfectly.

```
//In firstfile.scala

package A{ 
  class test{
    protected[test] var a=0
  }
}

package B{
  class test1 extends A.test{
    println(a)
  }
}
```

But when I put package B in some other file,then compilation fails saying not found value a

```
// In secondfile.scala

import A.test
package B{
  class test1 extends test{
    println(a)
  }
}
```

I am running this code in intellij.
what can be the reason of this? Are not the two codes same?

Comment: Does Scala find the class A.test?

Comment: Yes,it compiles fine if i dont use 'a' field in test1 class,all other public fields of test can be used without any prob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've found a bug. I can reproduce it in Eclipse with Scala IDE `2.0.0-beta9 with Scala 2.9.0-1`. First, let's create Foo.scala:

```
package a

class Foo {
  protected[Foo] var x = 0
}
```

and then Bar.scala:

```
package b

class Bar extends a.Foo {
  println(x) // Error: Not found: value x
}
```

Eclipse telling us, there is an error. But after cleaning a project this error disappears. And I checked, with `scalac` everything compiles with first attempt (who would doubt).

Update:

I've opened a ticket [#1000567](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets/1000567-error--when-value-was-defined-in-inherited-class-as-protected%5Bscope%5D-) on Scala IDE bugtracker regarding this issue.

Comment: u mean its a bug in intellij IDE?

Comment: @codetool definitely, I can't find another explanation. I'm looking for similar tickets on Scala IDE bugtracker now, but still not found anything.

Comment: ticket is for scala ide in eclipse. But my error is in idea intellij. How do i report that?

Comment: @codetool google has found [support page](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) on JetBrains site. Try it.